# How to i get data like age from dictionary within list python

Tags: python

I am trying to get data from this list for example the age, how do i get this and how can i count how many times it appears?

```
 my_list = [
    {'Name': 'Michael','Age': 29, 'Gender': 'Male', 'City':'Wisconsin'}
    {'Name': 'James','Age': 29, 'Gender': 'Male', 'City':'Tokyo'}
    {'Name': 'Diesel','Age': 29, 'Gender': 'Male', 'City':'Shanghai'}]
```

Comment: Can you tell us what you’ve tried so far?

Comment: Hi, all the data is in a json file thats why am finding it hard

Answer (score 1):

[List comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is what you need here:

```py
my_list = [
    {'Name': 'Michael', 'Age': 29, 'Gender': 'Male', 'City': 'Wisconsin'},
    {'Name': 'James', 'Age': 29, 'Gender': 'Male', 'City': 'Tokyo'},
    {'Name': 'Diesel', 'Age': 29, 'Gender': 'Male', 'City': 'Shanghai'}
]

ages = [person["Age"] for person in my_list]

# All the values having "Age" as key
print(ages)
>>> [29, 29, 29]

# The number of times the key "Age" is present
print(len(ages))
>>> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(k['Age'] for k in my_list if k.get('Age'))

Counter({29: 3})
```

Using `collections.Counter`